# IdHttp with SSL

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy, delphi-xe, indy10

I'm trying to use TIDHttp to access Paypal Api. I'm using Indy 10.6.2.0. Somehow when i try to get from https, i get this exception :

> Error connecting with SSL. error:14094410:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Here is my code.

```
  idhttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Type: application/json');
  idhttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: Bearer Access-Token');
  idhttp1.Request.username := cid;
  idhttp1.Request.Password := secret;
  idhttp1.ConnectTimeout := -1;
  idhttp1.get(https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token);
```

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Worked for me. Thanks for helping, as always

Comment: Right up until you try to apply a Delphi upgrade. Or perhaps install on another machine. You don't install third party libraries by modifying the libs shipped with Delphi. But what do I know?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't plan to upgrade Delphi, actually i don't upgrade it since 2008...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not always the best solution is the right solution ;)

Comment: The right solution is easy. It's almost as if your pride is driving your technical decision making.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue by downloading the correct Open SSL DLLs to use with Indy 10.6.2.0. The one that worked for me is on the link below :

https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-1.0.2-i386-win32.zip